# Binding Enter keystroke to jButton regardless of focus

Tags: java

I understand that the subject of this question has probably appeared on this site before, but when I see those examples, I still am not understanding how I can apply this functionality to my program in particular, especially since the placing of the statements is different, and also because they all seem to be saying different things. In posting this question I am hoping there is a simple way to set up this program ability in terms that I can understand.

Here is the code - I am using Netbeans IDE, if that helps.
What I specifically need is for Enter to trigger btnAddMarksActionPerformed.
Thank you in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*; 

public class U3A6_Marks extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList <Integer> marks = new ArrayList();

public U3A6_Marks() {
    initComponents();        
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void txtInput_markActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // I can't get rid of this method
}                                             

private void btnAddMarksActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    //Accept mark input and add to list
    String addedMarkInput = this.txtInput_mark.getText();
    int addedMark = Integer.parseInt(addedMarkInput);
    marks.add(addedMark);

    //Clear output box so getText doesn't get redundant text
    this.txtOutput_marksList.setText("");

    //Display marks with loop
    for (int i=0; i<marks.size(); i++ ){
    this.txtOutput_marksList.setText(txtOutput_marksList.getText()+ marks.get(i) +"\n");    
    }

    //Clear input box so user doesn't need to press backspace
    this.txtInput_mark.setText("");

}                                           

private void btnSortMarksActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    //Sort in ascending order
    Collections.sort(marks);

    //Redisplay required
    //Clear output box so getText doesn't get redundant text
    this.txtOutput_marksList.setText("");

    //Display marks with loop
    for (int i=0; i<marks.size(); i++ ){
    this.txtOutput_marksList.setText(txtOutput_marksList.getText()+ marks.get(i) +"\n");    
    }


}                                            

//Following line is empty
private void txtInput_markKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
}                                      




public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
   .....................................
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new U3A6_Marks().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnAddMarks;
private javax.swing.JButton btnProcessMarks;
private javax.swing.JButton btnSortMarks;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtInput_mark;
private javax.swing.JTextArea txtOutput_marksAnalysis;
private javax.swing.JTextArea txtOutput_marksList;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Here is initComponents. I want to add getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnAddMarks) in there, but its generated so I cant.

```
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtInput_mark = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    btnAddMarks = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtOutput_marksList = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    txtOutput_marksAnalysis = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    btnSortMarks = new javax.swing.JButton();
    btnProcessMarks = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel1.setText("Marks Processor Program");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Input Student Mark Here:");

    txtInput_mark.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    txtInput_mark.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtInput_markActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    txtInput_mark.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            txtInput_markKeyTyped(evt);
        }
    });

    btnAddMarks.setText("Add Mark");
    btnAddMarks.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnAddMarksActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    btnAddMarks.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            btnAddMarksKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtOutput_marksList.setEditable(false);
    txtOutput_marksList.setColumns(20);
    txtOutput_marksList.setLineWrap(true);
    txtOutput_marksList.setRows(5);
    txtOutput_marksList.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtOutput_marksList);

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel3.setText("Marks List");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel4.setText("Marks Analysis");

    txtOutput_marksAnalysis.setEditable(false);
    txtOutput_marksAnalysis.setColumns(20);
    txtOutput_marksAnalysis.setLineWrap(true);
    txtOutput_marksAnalysis.setRows(5);
    txtOutput_marksAnalysis.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txtOutput_marksAnalysis);

    btnSortMarks.setText("Sort");
    btnSortMarks.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnSortMarksActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    btnProcessMarks.setText("Process and Analyze");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(txtInput_mark, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(btnAddMarks, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 96, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING))
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(jScrollPane2))))
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(btnSortMarks, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 166, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(btnProcessMarks, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(txtInput_mark, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(btnAddMarks))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4))
            .addGap(7, 7, 7)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 330, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(btnSortMarks)
                .addComponent(btnProcessMarks))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void initComponents2(){
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnAddMarks);
}

private void txtInput_markActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

}                                             

private void btnAddMarksActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            


    //Accept mark input and add to list
    String addedMarkInput = this.txtInput_mark.getText();
    int addedMark = Integer.parseInt(addedMarkInput);
    marks.add(addedMark);

    //Clear output box so getText doesn't get redundant text
    this.txtOutput_marksList.setText("");

    //Display marks with loop
    for (int i=0; i<marks.size(); i++ ){
    this.txtOutput_marksList.setText(txtOutput_marksList.getText()+ marks.get(i) +"\n");    
    }

    //Clear input box so user doesn't need to press backspace twice
    this.txtInput_mark.setText("");

}
```

Comment: post initComponents()

Comment: Done. I want to add something in there, but I cannot. I made initComponents2 to add getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnAddMarks), and here's the thing - it works, but for some reason, it wont accept the ENTER button as input when the focus is on the txtInput_mark field. I have no idea why - it seems to work everywhere else.

Comment: @RtMa: because txtInput_mark is a JTextField, and JTextFields handle the enter key press. You either release the key bindings for the enter button for your JTextField (not sure I recommend this) or give it an ActionListener using the same Action that you're using for your enter key bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton( btnAddMarks );
```

Then when the user uses the Enter key it will behave like the user clicked on the button. This method will look after creating the appropriate `Key Bindings` for you. To understand more about `Key Bindings` read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

Edit:

> The issue is, the ENTER button only works to trigger that button when jTextField txtInput_mark is NOT in focus

KeyEvent are always dispatched to the component that has focus. So this means your text field is intercepting the event because you either added an `ActionListener` to the text field or are handling the Enter key in a KeyListener added to the text field. Get rid of the KeyListener and/or ActionListener.

Comment: One more question, then: where do I put this line?

Comment: I assume that means after this line:   private void btnAddMarksActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     ... now it says cannot find symbol variable frame

Comment: I removed tried frame altogether as well - it still doesn't work. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: You need to execute this code BEFORE you click on the button. Somewhere in you code you must have ` new btnAddMarks(...);`. Also "frame" refers to your JFrame. You may not have a variable in which case you can use "this" to refer to the frame since your class extend JFrame. If you don't know how to use a method then search the forum for examples of how the method is used. Learn by example.

Comment: I can't seem to edit the area where the button is created, but I am able to put getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnAddMarks); in the  private void txtInput_markActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { , which is would work perfectly fine for my purposes, since that would mean you can only press enter when the focus is there. However, what is happening is that btnAddMarks is only being highlighted in blue - it's not actually being triggered. EDIT: Actually, it can be triggered by ENTER, but only when the input box is out of focus, which I assume is because of where I placed it.

Comment: `I can't seem to edit the area where the button is created` So you add the code AFTER the method that creates the button is invoked. I can't tell you how to use an IDE since I've never used one. If you don't understand of to use the code generated by the IDE then why are you using the IDE? Spend your time learning how to write Java code.

Comment: `...which is would work perfectly fine for my purposes, since that would mean...` no that is not what it means. It means your code won't work. An ActionListener responds to events. So there is no way it can respond to the Enter key if you haven't even created the Key Bindings yet. If you only want `Enter` to work when the button has focus then you would NOT set the default button. See [Enter Key and Button](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/enter-key-and-button/) for more information and a different solution.

Comment: I couldn't edit that code, so I made: private void initComponents2(){getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btnAddMarks);}, right after the making of the buttons. The issue is, the ENTER button only works to trigger that button when jTextField txtInput_mark is NOT in focus. I want enter to trigger regardless of focus, or at least when jTextField txtInput_mark is IN focus. Is there anything else I should add so it works in those conditions?

Comment: @RtMa, see edit and if you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Your idea to remove the actionListener on the text field worked. I deleted the old text field and replaced it with another of the same name, since for some reason I couldn't edit/delete the listener code  I made out of desperation for that text field. The code is fully functional. Thank you for your time and patience.